# Change Texture In Scene Editor Programmatically

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode, sceneeditor

I've added a color sprite, named "arm" to my Scene Editor but for a bunch of reasons I need to access that color sprite and change the texture programmatically. Another way of stating my goal, I want to link the node to my GameScene swift file and change texture using a texture from an array. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: @cc. I've seen you answer similar questions, would love to get your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, you want to link the sprite node from your GameScene.sks file to your GameScene.swift file.

To do this, in GameScene.swift near the top (under the "class GameScene: SKScene {") use this:

```
var armNode: SKSpriteNode?
```

In your didMove(to view:) section do this:

```
armNode = childNode(withName: "arm") as? SKSpriteNode
```

Now 3 different ways to change the color/texture of the SKSpriteNode depending on what you are doing:

```
armNode.colour = UIColor.red

armNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "your arm image here")

armNode.texture = textureArray[2]
```

The 3rd version uses a texture from an array of textures

Comment: this was very useful, thank you. I'm sure I'll need more help, I wish there was a way for us to communicate more directly.

Comment: do you know how to add a video? Assuming i have to first create property 'var videoNode: SKVideoNode?' but get lost when trying to set the property with a video.

Comment: In the documentation it gives you sample code on how to add a video and play it. [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skvideonode/adding_a_video_to_a_scene)